# hibernate one-to-one mapping, how to make two entities have same primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entity `Resource`(table resource) and `VideoInfo`(table video_info), there is one-to-one unidirectional relationship from `VideoInfo` to `Resource`. The following code save one-to-one relationship but the saved column resource.id doesn't equal to video_info.resourceId. Is there anything wrong with the annotations? I know I can manually set video_info.resourceId equal to Resource.id, does any automatic way exist?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Resource r=new Resource();
    r.setName("test");
    r.setPath("foo");
    r.setType("video");
    VideoInfo videoInfo=new VideoInfo();
    videoInfo.setResource(r);
    Session session=Database.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.save(videoInfo);
        transaction.commit();
    }catch (Exception e){
        transaction.rollback();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(r.getId());
    System.out.println(videoInfo.getResourceId());
}
```

output:

```
19
0
```

VideoInfo entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "video_info")
public class VideoInfo {
    @Id
    private int resourceId;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Integer time;
    @Column(name = "actors")
    private String actors;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resourceId")
    private Resource resource;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Resource entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resource")
public class Resource {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the same primary key for both the Entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my question: As this link [@OneToOne With Shared Primary Key, Revisited](https://dzone.com/articles/onetoone-shared-primary-key)  say, I should use @MapsId annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "video_info")
public class VideoInfo {
    @Id
    private int resourceId;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Integer time;
    @Column(name = "actors")
    private String actors;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resourceId")
    @MapsId
    private Resource resource;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation ?

Like this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Resource resource;
```

Follow this [link](http://fruzenshtein.com/one-to-one-unidirectional-primary-key/) for better understanding